# Mysql Select only percentage of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use the second column (art_count) to show only those rows containing X percent of total art_count.

My data:

```
title   art_count
a       3
b       12
c       9
d       4
e       45
```

My query so far:

```
SELECT title, COUNT(art) AS art_count
FROM table1
GROUP BY art HAVING ... ?
```

Tried it with SUM without success.

Comment: First, where is the art column in your data? Furthermore a simple **WHERE** clause should be sufficient here. In general you'd want to avoid HAVING especially when you do not really need it. Is there anything else you'd like to add to the question?

Comment: @user3481307 You've also forgotten to include the art_stock column. This will help responders better understand your question and produce clear answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT title, COUNT(art) AS art_count
FROM table1
GROUP BY art 
HAVING art_count >= (select count(*) * X / 100 from table1)
```

You need to insert a value for `X`

Comment: Will `count(*)` count all the rows in the table or selected results only?

Comment: `count(*)` will count the records of every group. And only the groups matching the HAVING conditions will be displayed