# How to use percentage in a Laravel query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

The following query will result in 100 rows :

```
$qtop = Quest::where('ttype',$id)      
                     ->where('country', $ucountry ) 
                     ->where('score', '>' , 240 ) 
                    ->orderby('score', 'desc')  
                    // ->take(25)
                    ->get();
```

Instead of using `->take(25)` how can I take 25% of the total rows ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql Select only percentage of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763342/mysql-select-only-percentage-of-rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in plain sql server syntax you can use *TOP 25 PERCENT*

```
select TOP 25 PERCENT * from table
```

For plain mysql you need to use nested queries @see [Convert SQL Server query to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522433/convert-sql-server-query-to-mysql/5522462#5522462) :

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT table.*, @counter := @counter +1 counter
    FROM (select @counter:=0) initvar, table
    ORDER BY score
) X
WHERE X.counter <= (25/100 * @counter)
ORDER BY score
```

Comment: I think this is SQL server syntax not Mysql.

Comment: There's really no such thing as "plain SQL". There's various SQL standards, and a whole bunch of dialects, all of which tend to contradict the others.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the documentation;

```
$users = DB::table('users')->skip(10)->take(5)->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset